# oracle dbms max returning all values

Tags: sql, oracle, select, max, aggregate-functions

I am trying to run the following query on an Oracle express edition database.

```
SELECT SIGHTING_ID, MAX(DISTANCE)
FROM
(
    SELECT SIGHTING_ID,
          SQRT(POWER(LATITUDE + 28, 2) + POWER(LONGITUDE - 151, 2)) AS DISTANCE
    FROM SIGHTINGS
)
GROUP BY SIGHTING_ID;
```

The purpose of the query is to return **The SIGHTING_ID and DISTANCE for the sighting with the maximum distance from the co-ords (-28, 151)**

The description for the table SIGHTINGS is as follows

```
 desc SIGHTINGS
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 SIGHTING_ID                               NOT NULL NUMBER
 SPOTTER_ID                                         NUMBER
 BIRD_ID                                            NUMBER
 LATITUDE                                           NUMBER
 LONGITUDE                                          NUMBER
 SIGHTING_DATE                                      DATE
 DESCRIPTION                                        VARCHAR2(255)
```

When I run the query instead of selecting the maximum distance it selects and shows the entire list of sightings and their respective distances. SIGHTINGS has a large amount of tuples but below is a small list of the current output

```
 SIGHTING_ID MAX(DISTANCE)
 ----------- -------------
 264172    2.01556444
 264174    2.34029913
 264180    2.87647354
 264198    .637887137
 264205    2.08568933
 264211    .232594067
 264215    2.34104677
 264221           .75
 264224    .148660687
 264235    .684470598
```

My question is how do I make it so that the MAX aggregate function works so that it returns just the maximum distance and the respect SIGHTING_ID?

Answer (score 2):

Use Oracle's [`rownum`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html) :

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT SIGHTING_ID, SQRT(POWER(LATITUDE + 28, 2) + POWER(LONGITUDE - 151, 2)) AS DISTANCE
     FROM SIGHTINGS
     ORDER BY distance DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

The reason you're getting a record for each `SIGHTING_ID` is because you are grouping by it. A group by clause means -> give me 1 record for each combination of the columns mentioned inside the clause .

Comment: If there are two records with the maximum distance in that case it would skip one of the records.

Comment: And how do you know that's not what he wants? @hemalp108

Comment: I've no doubt in your answer, let him decide what he wants. I am just asking it for my curiosity.

Comment: Thank you so much, worked like a charm after removing the extra bracket

Comment: @hemalp108 . . . The question is pretty clear:  "to return The SIGHTING_ID and DISTANCE for the sighting".  This is all in the *singular*.  The OP may want something else, but that is not the question s/he asked.

Comment: No problem mate, please mark one of the answers as accepted if it solved your problem @LeePhillips .

Comment: If i wanted to use the max aggregate function in the code what would i need to group by to only return one value?

Comment: To return 1 value you need to **not** use the group by clause at all. `SELECT MAX(val) FROM Table` . Note that you shouldn't do it when you need to return multiple values including columns without an aggregation function on them, like in this case `SIGHTING_ID` @LeePhillips

Comment: The correct solution for this kind of problems is the first/last aggregate function (as I demonstrate in my answer). https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm

Comment: Actually the fastest way will probably be my way. The first/last functions are prefered \ required when needed to return more than 1 row . @mathguy

Comment: @sagi - That would be interesting (I may do some testing if I find a few minutes). Your solution requires the ordering of the full rowset, which is O(n log(n)). Finding min/max is only O(log(n)). So it will be fun to see how a solution that requires total ordering is faster than one that only seeks the min.

Comment: @mathguy How is finding the max/min O(log(n)) ? I guess you mean O(n) ?

Comment: Finding min/max is faster, though I don't think `FIRST/LAST` has the same performance as `MIN/MAX` . Never the less, "The correct solution" for this answer is what the OP likes best. Begginers on SQL might and probably willl prefer this way, as it is easier to understand. Your solution is not the correct one, its just another one. @mathguy

Comment: @FrankSchmitt - You are right again. Not enough coffee yet!

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle 12c+, you can use ANSI standard functionality:

```
SELECT SIGHTING_ID,
      SQRT(POWER(LATITUDE + 28, 2) + POWER(LONGITUDE - 151, 2)) AS DISTANCE
FROM SIGHTINGS
ORDER BY distance DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

In earlier versions, @sagi's solution is probably the best way.

Comment: The correct solution for this kind of problems is the first/last aggregate function (as I demonstrate in my answer). https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions056.htm

Comment: @mathguy Your wording is misleading. Your approach is *one of several* correct solutions - Gordon Linoff's is another one, and sagi's yet another.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt - You are right, I should have said "best", not "correct." For Oracle 12c, Gordon's solution is equally good; I was disagreeing with his assessment for earlier versions. I would edit my comments but on SO that is not possible.

Comment: @mathguy . . . I prefer Sagi's solution, because it more easily generalizes to multiple columns (or all columns within a row).

Answer (score 0):

```
select min(sighting_id) keep (dense_rank first order by distance) as sighting_id,
       min(distance)                                              as distance
from sightings;
```

This will find the row or rows with the shortest `distance`, and from those rows (and those only), if there are ties (the shortest `distance` is achieved by two or more `sighting id`'s), it selects the one with the smallest `sighting_id`. If instead you want the one with the greatest `latitude` (say), still from those with the shortest `distance`, change `order by distance` to `order by distance, latitude desc`. Other combinations are treated the same way.